# MySQL 5.6 - query varchar with single quotes

Tags: mysql, varchar, mysql-5.6, mysql4, mysql-5.7

Please look at the screenshot below to see the issue.

[image]

Comment: Try `SELECT HEX(code) FROM diag_code WHERE code = 001.1` to see if there are any `NUL` or tab or space characters you're not seeing.

Comment: @EdGibbs That doesn't work.

Comment: Glimpse, please provide more detail than "that doesn't work". You don't say *how* it "doesn't work", you haven't said the column's data type, and I had to infer what your issue was in the first place.

Comment: Pasting in plain text works a lot better than posting tiny screenshots.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffa8b/1).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is the length/size of the varchar "code" column. MySQL 4 will allow you to insert and query values larger than the allowed size. I don't know about inserting, but for MySQL 5, it doesn't allow you to query specifically for a value larger than the column size.

In MySQL 5 where the code column is a varchar(3), I could do "select * from billing where code = '101'", but not "select * from billing where code = '101.1'".